# getting ReplicaSetNoPrimary and MongoServerSelectionError error while connecting MongoDB with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to connect to mongodb but getting below error could you please help

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
mongo.connect('mongodb://usernamexyz:passwordxyz@hostmxy-mw-e6-u1238.nam.nsroot.net:47017/sampleDB?replicaSet=NAME_2436&readPreference=primary&authSource=admin&w=1', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true  })
.then(() => console.log("Mongodb connected"))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

And the error i am getting as below

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 155.30.360.129:37017 closed
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Fintech\NodeFirstApp\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:448:30)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7) {
  name: 'MongoServerSelectionError',
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map {
      'hostmxy-mw-e6-u1238.nam.nsroot.net:47017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  },
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to the replica-set from the Mongo Shell?

Answer (score 29):

Go to Mongodb where you created a cluster and under "ipwhitelist" click on the edit IP address button and then choose "Add current IP address"

Answer (score 6):

There was a firewall issue for me, and here are the steps i followed:

1. Search for Windows Firewall with Advanced Security
2. Select `Outbound Rules`
3. Select `New Rule`
4. Select `Port` in `Rule Type`, Click next
5. Select `TCP` and `Specific remote ports` and write in there **`27015-27017`**
6. Save the rule
   This worked for me :)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6):

I setup replica set on mongod server in order to have oplog facility and use it to sync database programmatically with golang client.
It was working fine with local windows server.

```
mongod.exe --dbpath $dpath --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 --port $port --replSet rs0
mongo.exe' -port $port --eval 'rs.initiate()'
```

When I used docker it showed me that ReplicaSetNoPrimary Error.

```
docker run --name mongo21 -d -p 27021:27017 mongo  --bind_ip_all  --replSet rs0
docker container exec mongo21 mongosh --eval 'rs.initiate()' 127.0.0.1
```

I noticed that perl client as well as Robo3 T, mongosh connected to the server localhost:27021 without problem.
mongosh shows which mongo uri it uses:

```
mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.1.9
```

I found I can specify client option before connect:

```
clientOpts := options.Client().ApplyURI(uri).SetDirect(true)
client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOpts)
```

That option fixed golang client connection issue.

Comment: you can set clientOpts shorter: clientOpts := options.Client().ApplyURI(uri).SetDirect(true)

Comment: indeed the direct connection solved it:
const client = new MongoClient(url, {directConnection: true});

Answer (score 3):

Some MongoDB implementations as a service such as IBM Cloud, GCP or AWS might need a certificate to be able to connect.   That was my case.  The problem was resolved when I added a certificate to the docker file and then passed the parameters as options

```
let options = {
    tls: true,
    tlsCAFile: `/path/to/cert`,
    useUnifiedTopology: true 
};

// connects to a MongoDB database
MongoClient.connect(connectionString, options)
```

Reference https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/databases-for-mongodb?topic=databases-for-mongodb-mongodb-external-app

Comment: I missed the `tls` option.  Adding the tls and the certificate solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with this. It was fixed when I added the current IP address to IP whitelist inside of MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error while connecting to MongoDB atlas.
You have to do following things.
1. allow outbound port 27015-27017 in firewall in your system.
2. update the latest MongoDB and NodeJs.
3. whitelist your system IP in MongoDB atlas cluster under network access.

It worked for me. I hope it works for you also.

Answer (score 0):

Updating "Network Access" did not work for me. What worked for me was to update "Database Access" by "Autogenerate Secure Password" and **make sure to click "Update User" to save new password!**

> MongoDB Atlas > Database Access > complete 3 steps in image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was using Atlas Mongo Cluster and using 'mongomirror' I am trying to push the data from one replicaset cluster to another. In the process, I was getting this error..

After ot of research, I understood that, the name of cluster visible in UI should not be used.. instead you need to run the below command

```
rs.status()
```

This will give a JSON output which has the RS name and respective primary and secondary node endpoints you need to use.

In my case, for abc-temp-shard-cluster, the cluster name I got by running the above command was something like below

```
atlas-12avca-shard-0/atlas-12avca-shard-00-00.1aqer5.mongodb.net:27017,atlas-12avca-shard-00-01.1aqer5.mongodb.net:27017,atlas-12avca-shard-00-02.1aqer5.mongodb.net:27017
```

Answer (score 0):

try to enable ipv6 support at mongo server using --ipv6 flag

```
mongod --dbpath="D:/data_path" -replSet rs0 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0,127.0.0.1,localhost,::1 --ipv6
```

Answer (score 0):

To build onto existing answers, one possibility is that Atlas filters out connections based on your IP address.

You can enable different connections by going to "Security" > "Network Access", where "Security" is located within the left sidebar of the Atlas website.

Answer (score 0):

**reason: TopologyDescription { type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',}**

2024 i was getting this error, go to network access from side bar and your current IP

Answer (score -2):

I had this issue on a public university's wireless network, switched over to my hotspot and the issue resolved