# Error : "Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

My node app gives me this message 
"Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist".

I've already added my current IP address along with the 0.0.0.0  on the IP whitelist.

Below is a picture of the error message and the code I've written to connect it.
I'm new to node.js and mongodb. I looked through all the solutions on here but none of them were able to solve this.

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyparser.json());

mongoose
     .connect("mongodb+srv://<username:password>@my-cluster.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority", 
     { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
     .then(() => console.log( 'Database Connected' ))
     .catch(err => console.log( err ));

    app.listen(3003)
```

This is the error I receive after running nodemon.

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
MongooseError [MongooseServerSelectionError]: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/.
    at new MongooseServerSelectionError (C:\Users\anna james\Dropbox\MERN_SHOPPING_LIST\back\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\serverSelection.js:24:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\anna james\Dropbox\MERN_SHOPPING_LIST\back\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:823:32)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\anna james\Dropbox\MERN_SHOPPING_LIST\back\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:333:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\anna james\Dropbox\MERN_SHOPPING_LIST\back\server.js:9:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1177:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:900:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  message: "Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/.",
  name: 'MongooseServerSelectionError',
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map {
      'cluster1-shard-00-01-m3rzz.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'cluster1-shard-00-02-m3rzz.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'cluster1-shard-00-00-m3rzz.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  },
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

[Error Message and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZSPr.png)

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow! Could you add a code snippet and the log in text format instead of a screenshot? It's easier to read for the community that could access to SO with a mobile, tablet or other device? Thanks

Comment: thanks for letting me know. I reformatted it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60563988/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-mongooseserverselectionerror/60584076#60584076  this can help you

Comment: thanks for the recommendation. But I already gave that a try before I created this post

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Are you using proxy?? please try with different internet connection first.

Comment: Adding to this answer, if you had a VPN on while adding your IP to MongoDB Cloud and you don't have it on anymore (or vice-versa) you'll get this error

Answer (score 73):

**Try doing this**:- `MongoDB Atlas` -> `NetworkAccess` -> `Edit` -> `Allow Any`

This worked for me!

Comment: He already mentioned that he set 0.0.0.0 (presumably with /0 ) on the IP whitelist which es the result of your suggestion. If it worked for you, you had a different problem.

Comment: Yaa, I didn't know what 0.0.0.0 meant back then. But later when I knew, I saw that this answer is helping people, so I did not consider deleting it.

Comment: `Allow Any` doesn't appear to be an option anymore under `IP Access List`

Comment: @fIwJlxSzApHEZIl It's available at the moment

Answer (score 12):

```
Follow below steps:
1] Go to https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas
2] login to your mongodb atlas account
3] Click on network access

i] if you have already added ip address, then here you can see ip access list
a] click on delete 

ii] if you have not already added ip address, then just follow below steps:

4] click on add ip address
5] select 'add current ip address' or if you want you can also select 'allow access from anywhere'
6] type in comment if you want
7] click on confirm button
8] this will show pending loader, wait until it shows active status
9] now restart your server on terminal by typing 'npm start'

-- That's it!
```

Comment: Restarting server is really important

Answer (score 9):

I was able to solve the connection problem to the server on MongoDB by doing this change.

MongoDB Atlas -> NetworkAccess -> Edit -> Allowed Access from Anywhere

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks @Ozer

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if it is the right reason. But, its working for me when i disconnect the VPN.

When connected to VPN, I'm getting below error message.

**Error**:
"Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist".

Answer (score 8):

If the password is correct and you have `allowed access from anywhere` and you still getting the same error then, **The problem is with your network which has a firewall**. I solved my issue by just changing the network because mine was having a firewall.

Comment: samething happened to me on cwp

Answer (score 5):

It's not always problem with the ip. Can have problem in db name , username or password.Then also connection failed.

Comment: This is so true! I had same error but my issue was "Database Access", see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70970887/1235675)

Answer (score 3):

At times, it may be due to system settings as well.

In my case it was server system's date & time, it was not updated to current date & time settings, hence the connection to db from the server was refused. Updated the same, and restart the server, connection was successful.

Comment: Thank you! This was tripping me up. I was running a dev setup using USB Live Ubuntu and I keep in on UTC to prevent it resetting my computer's clock.

Answer (score 3):

In your Mongo project, go to the network access section, and edit the IP to allow access from anywhere (0.0.0.0/0). Ensure that strong credentials (username and password) are used for all database users when allowing access from anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

**As [lakshitha-samod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63376128/4407597) said, it's not only the IP address issue, It may be different**

(In my case I was using my login password instead db password)

```
mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<clusterName>.p9ykp.mongodb.net/<databaseName>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

**1. IP Address (for cross check)**

Go to Network Access -> Add/ Edit ->Add Current IP Address or Allow Access from Anywhere

**1. check DB user/ create one**

Go to Database access -> create new / edit and reset the password if don't remember

**2. Database name**

Go to your cluster -> Browse Collections -> select a collection(database name: **ex:** sample_training)

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue here is an example broken down:

mongodb+srv://<**userWithAccessToDB**>:<**password**>@dev-12abc.mongodb.net/<**yourDatabaseName**>?retryWrites=true&w=majority

1. Check the username at the spot **userWithAccessToDB** has access
2. Check that the password is correct in the **password** part of the string
3. Check that the database exists and you are connecting to the correct one in the **yourDatabaseName** slot
4. Check that you have the ***+srv*** from the beginning of the string

> mongodb+srv

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for so long, then finally thought to check the firewall on my router. I had set it to the highest security level at one point, and set it one level lower instead, and that fixed it!

The default IP address for routers is usually 192.168.0.1, but it may differ in some cases.  Just go to that IP, login as admin, and try changing your firewall settings. Of course, there's a trade off of some security, but in my case, this setting was messing up other things as well, such as smart device connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

if you are used any proxy or certificate based internet then this type problem is raise.Try different internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

If your server is setup in VPC -> Private Subnet. In this case, EC2 is using NAT gateway(which is setup in publicsubnet), so in atlas whitelist, add NAT gateway ip.

Answer (score 1):

The IP address seen by Atlas is not necessarily the IP address of your workstations. If behind a router that does NAT or using VPN the address seen is the one of the router or the exit point of the VPN.

First try to Allow Access From Anywhere. If it works it is most likely because you whitelisted an IP address that is not your public address. Find your public IP with `https://www.whatismyip.com/`

If the above does not work then we need more information to help.

Answer (score 0):

To whitelist an IP address, go to your target cluster on MongoDB Atlas. Next, go to Network Access under the Security tab. On the IP Whitelist tab, click on Add IP address. Type your IP address manually under Whitelist Entry, then click Confirm. run your code it should run without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Three things I did that solved the issue:

1. Disabling my firework.
2. Allowing access of Atlas IP from anywhere. How --> My Network Access > Edit(My IP Address) > set your new IP as 0.0.0.0/0 and confirm.
3. Updating my password by MongoDB Atlas > Database Access > complete 3 steps in the below images image (credit to @piouson ). Also, copying the updated password to my MongoDB compress and mongooge.connect in the server.js
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

If there is no issue by the end of the MongoDB URI so try disabling the firewall and then connecting the MongoDB it works then you will have to make the MongoDB cluster IP address whitelist and then you can enable the firewall again with no issue.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the solutions worked for you, check the date and time of your OS. If it is incorrect Atlas refuses the connection but still gives the same error suggesting an IP whitelist.

If you are on WSL, try checking the date and time of the WSL distro as well. It is supposed to sync with Windows but sometimes it gets out of sync. If that's the case you can use the following command to re-sync the WSL clock with the Windows.

```
sudo hwclock -s
```

If you can connect with Compass but not with WSL, this is most likely the issue.

Answer (score 0):

remove any **proxy** or **vpn** if you are using, then go to
`network setting > Add new Ip and select Allow access from any where`
If still not work then again go to
`network setting > Add new Ip > this time add current Ip`
**Then this will work 110%.**
If any issue feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

`MongoDB Atlas > Security > Network Access > +Add IP Address > Allow access from anywhere` would definitely work, **but in reality it is not a safe choice**, since you are basically allowing anyone to connect to your db from any IP address (from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 i.e. 0.0.0.0/0).

Instead, you can figure out your server public IP address, and then `+Add IP Address` for that public IP address(es) only as a CIDR range.
For example,

1. say your local machine IP address is `56.12.345.45`, you would add `56.12.345.45` or `56.12.345.45/32` to allow connections from your local machine only and not from anywhere else. Find your local machine's pub IP address here: https://whatismyipaddress.com/
2. say you hosted a test app in a replit server which has a public IP address `45.12.345.67`, you may need to add `45.12.345.67/8` to allow connections from `45.0.0.0 - 45.255.255.255` range only and not from anywhere else. (Replit free hosting usually requires this big IP range to be added). You can try to see if a smaller range works for you e.g. `45.12.345.67/24` or `45.12.345.67/16`. The smaller & specific the range is the better & secure your db. Find your server's pub IP address using the domain name: https://www.whatsmydns.net/

Answer (score 0):

Open the database instance
[image]

Click on the Network access option from the right bar
[image]

You can see that the Current IP Address has not added. You will not be able to connect to databases from this address.

click on add IP address in the top right corner
[image]
click on ALLOW ACCESS FROM ANYWHERE or type 0.0.0.0/0 in the access list entry and click confirm.
Then restart the application or server.

This is for the development environment.
In production make sure you add only the required IP address or valid allowed IP address in the access list entry for better privacy and security for private databases. if required or the database is public then you can use the above method.

Even turning off the VPN works sometimes but not all the time. check proxy settings on the laptop. or connected to the public network with a dynamic Connection also causes the problem

Answer (score -1):

Try keeping these questions in mind when you face such an issue with your mongodB that:

Did I changed my IP address before I started working with my mongodb again after a long break?
If no, then please change it because usually mongodb removes it after every 6 hours.

Did I moved from the place where I worked last time?
If yes, then please change your IP again and activate it.

Please do visit the link https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/mongodb-atlas-login-ip-whitelisting/#whitelist-multiple-or-additional-ip-addresses and learn more about why you get such error and how deal with them. It helps a lot.

Answer (score -1):

You can try after turning off your VPN.