# Express function failing to get data from Mongo Atlas database

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm written an express function to perform a GET request on a mongo atlas database collection. However, upon testing it in Postman I get the following error logged:
`MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster.`

I've configured my database IP whitelist so that it can take requests from any IP, as follows:
Network Access -> EDIT -> Access list Entry: 0.0.0.0/0.

Any suggestions as to why it isn't working?

Here's the express route:

```
app.get('/api/all-reviews', (req,res) => {
    Review.find()
    .then((result) => {
        res.send(result)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
})
```

Here's the model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const reviewSchema = new Schema({
    userName:String,
    stars:String,
    title:String,
    photo:String,
    blurb:String
}, {timestamps:true})

const Review = mongoose.model('review', reviewSchema)

module.exports = Review
```

And here's a sample of the data being returned:

```
id:5ff59a7a027e312bb815b3c4
userName:"testuserName"
stars:"1"
title:"title"
photo:"photoURL"
blurb:"blurb"
createdAt:2021-01-06T11:09:46.505+00:00
updatedAt:2021-01-06T11:09:46.505+00:00
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61937581/error-could-not-connect-to-any-servers-in-your-mongodb-atlas-cluster

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem - I had put the wrong collection name in my schema. I changed it from 'review' to 'reviews', which made the GET request work.