# User Authentication not working as expected

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, google-oauth, passport.js

I created a web app that authenticates users using Passport.js where they are able to log-in or register either using the web form or google authentication. The web app is working fine and as expected locally, however, when deployed, it is allowing me to register but, when logged in, I try to press any button, it logs me out asks me to sign in again. The log is giving me a bunch of 304 and 302 status code errors. I don't know what is wrong. Please help.

Once I log in, I expect it to keep me logged in until I sign out. Instead, once I log in and try to use the web app, it logs me out. I am using: express, mongoose, session, express-passport, passport-local-mongoose, passport-google-oauth20, mongoose-findorcreate

Here is the link to my deployed web app: https://upset-gilet-lion.cyclic.app/

Here is a screenshot of deployed app logs:
[logs screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwGMo.png)

Here is my app.js code:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const findOrCreate = require("mongoose-findorcreate")

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public/"));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

// Initializing Session
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

// Initializing Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Connecting to MongoDB using Mongoose
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);

const mongodb = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/userDB"

const mongodbNet = "mongodb+srv://admin-bhoami:"+ process.env.PASSWORD +"@secretscluster.uztbzho.mongodb.net/userDB";

mongoose.connect(mongodbNet, function(err){
    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to MongoDB');
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB');
    }
});

// Creating a new User Database
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    email: String,
    password: String,
    googleId: String,
    secret: Array
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

// Set Local Login Strategy
passport.use(User.createStrategy());

// Serialize and Deserialize
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

// Google Authentication Strategy that authenticates users using a Google Account and OAuth 2.0 tokens.
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "https://upset-gilet-lion.cyclic.app/auth/google/secrets", //"http://localhost:3000/auth/google/secrets"
    },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    User.findOrCreate({username: profile.emails[0].value, googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));

// Home Page
app.route("/")
    .get(function(req, res) {
        res.render("home");
    });

// Google Authentication Route
app.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ["openid", "profile", "email"] }));

app.get("/auth/google/secrets", 
  passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/signin" }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect("/secrets");
});

// Sign-Up Page
app.route("/signup")
    .get(function(req, res) {
        res.render("signup");
    })
    .post(function(req, res) {
        User.register({username: req.body.username}, req.body.password, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.redirect("/signup");
            } else {
                passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {
                    res.redirect("/secrets");
                });
            }
        });
    });

// Sign-In Page
app.route("/signin")
    .get(function(req, res) {
        res.render("signin");
    })
    .post(function(req, res) {
        // Check database to see if the username provided exists in it.
        User.findOne({username: req.body.username}, function(err, foundUser) {
            // If username found, create an object "user" to store username and password which was used for login
            if (foundUser) {
                const user = new User ({
                    username: req.body.username,
                    password: req.body.password
                });
                // Use the "user" object to compare against username and password stored in Database.
                // The code below will either return false is no match was found or it will return the 'found user'.
                passport.authenticate("local", function (err, user) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        // the 'user' below is the user returned from passport.authenticate callback; it will either be false if no match was found or the user
                        if (user) {
                            // If the user is found, then he/she is logged in or they are redirected to sign in page.
                            req.login(user, function(err) {
                                res.redirect("/secrets");
                            })
                        } else {
                            res.redirect("/signin");
                        }
                    }
                }) (req, res);
            // If no username is found, redirect to sign in page; i.e. user does not exists
            } else {
                res.redirect("/signin");
            }
        });
    });

// Secrets Page
app.route("/secrets")
    .get(function(req, res) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            User.find({secret: {$ne: null}}, function(err, users) {
                if (!err) {
                    if (users) {
                        res.render("secrets", {usersWithSecrets: users});
                    } else {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        } else {
            res.redirect("/signin");
        }
    });

// Sign-Out Route
app.route("/signout")
    .get(function(req, res) {
        req.logout(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.redirect("/")
            }
        });
    });

// Submit Route
app.route("/submit")
    .get(function(req, res) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            res.render("submit");
        } else {
            res.redirect("/signin");
        }
    })
    .post(function(req, res) {
        const submittedSecret = req.body.secret;
        if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
            req.user.secret.push(submittedSecret);
            req.user.save(function() {
                res.redirect("/secrets");
            })
        } else {
            res.redirect("/signin");
        }
    });


// Delete Route
app.route("/delete")
    .get(function(req, res) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            res.render("delete", {secrets: req.user.secret});
        } else {
            res.redirect("/signin");
        }
    })
    .post(function(req, res) {
        if(req.isAuthenticated()){
            User.findById(req.user.id, function (err,foundUser){
              foundUser.secret.splice(foundUser.secret.indexOf(req.body.secret),1);
              foundUser.save(function (err) {
                if(!err){
                  res.redirect("/secrets");
                }
              });
            });
          }else {
            res.redirect("/signin");
          }
    });

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log("Server started on Port ${PORT}");
});
```

Comment: Did you read the error you’re receiving? “One common reason is that you’re trying to access the database from not whitelisted IP address.” (http://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist)

Comment: Yes, I did read it, this is what is on Cyclic's docs:
"Cyclic apps do not have static IP's for white listing with Atlas and Cyclic does not offer private networking on free tier.

Setting 0.0.0.0/0 will enable access to your service cluster from all IP's and make it possible for services to authenticate via connection string." (https://docs.cyclic.sh/how-to/using-mongo-db)

And I did add 0.0.0.0/0 to whitelist. It gave me this error, even after it is whitelisted.

Comment: Have you tried these tips? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61937581/error-could-not-connect-to-any-servers-in-your-mongodb-atlas-cluster

Comment: Yes, I did. None of them worked.

Comment: Turns out it wasn't a problem with my mongoDB connection. It was a problem with session storing. I used 'connect-mongo' (https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo) package from npm and the web app started working as expected. Thank you for your help though. I appreciate it. :)