# Can't not connect with mognodb atlas server

Tags: mongodb, cluster-analysis, atlas

Database connection error: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

I am trying to connect with mongodb Atlas cluster0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error : "Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61937581/error-could-not-connect-to-any-servers-in-your-mongodb-atlas-cluster)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MongoDB Atlas, follow the following steps:

1. Go to network access
2. Add IP Address

[image: An image showing the steps to add/ allowlist IPs to connect]