# Can't connect to mongodb atlas on nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
   mongoose.connect(
process.env.DB_CONFIG,
{
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useCreateIndex: true,
}
)
.then((x) => {
console.log(
  `Connected to MongoDB!`
);
})
.catch((err) => {
console.error("Error connecting to mongo", err);
});
```

This is the piece of code I have been working on and this works fine until this day.
I don't know why and got an error like this:

```
  Error connecting to mongo MongooseServerSelectionError: connection timed out
at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (D:\projects\medium-clone\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:846:32)
at D:\projects\medium-clone\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:351:10
at D:\projects\medium-clone\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at promiseOrCallback (D:\projects\medium-clone\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (D:\projects\medium-clone\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1149:10)
at Mongoose.connect (D:\projects\medium-clone\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:350:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\projects\medium-clone\server\index.js:12:4)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
 reason: TopologyDescription {
 type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
 setName: 'atlas-vwy17h-shard-0',
 maxSetVersion: null,
maxElectionId: null,
servers: Map(3) {
  'authcluster-shard-00-00.ris23.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
  'authcluster-shard-00-01.ris23.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
  'authcluster-shard-00-02.ris23.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
},
stale: false,
compatible: true,
compatibilityError: null,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30,
heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
localThresholdMS: 15,
commonWireVersion: 9
```

}
}

I tried adding my ip to network access in mongodb dashboard but didn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64548380/10209642

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens because of your own internet connection when you use mobile hotspot. In this case adding your IP  may never work unfortunately because your IP may probably change every time you reconnect. When I had the same issue I restarted my connection and allowed all IPs in access network. And also make sure that your connection is stable.

Comment: i allowed all ips in access network but did't work either